# Disable HTTPS for a domain that shares IP with another domain that is under HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, redirect, https

I am running into a weird problem trying to disable HTTPS for one domain, but the other domain has HTTPS. They both are different websites running on a dedicated server, sharing the same IP address for the domains. 
However, I have a domain that does not have a SSL certificate, but the other does. I want to disable HTTPS for the non-certified domain while leaving the other domain with HTTPS on.

I have two different separate vhosts in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`,

**domain1.org** (no HTTPS)

```
server {

    listen                      80;
    server_name                 www.domain1.org domain1.org;
    root                        /var/www/domain1.org;
    index                       index.html index.php index.htm;

    error_log                   /var/www/logs/domain1.errors.log;

    [ ... ]
```

**domain2.com** (with HTTPS)

```
server {

    listen                      443 ssl;
    server_name                 domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    # INCLUDE SSL CERTIFICATE
    include                     sites-enabled/domain2_ssl_include; 

    root                        /home/domain2/www/www;
    index                       index.html index.php index.htm;

    [ ... ]
```

I've included a listener to the port 443 for domain1.org, but once I do that, I get an aborted error from Firefox saying (when accessing https://domain1.org):

> This Connection is Untrusted
>
> You have asked Firefox to connect securely to domain1.org, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

I opened the technical data, it appears that the domain1.org is using the domain2.com SSL certificate:

> domain1.org uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names:
>    *.domain2.com , domain2.com
>
> (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)

So I added this to domain1.org vhost configuration:

```
server {

    server_name                 domain1.org www.domain1.org;

    listen                      443 ssl;

    rewrite ^ http://domain1.org permanent;
}
```

Which still gets me prompted with the Firefox error.

Now... when I access to http://domain1.org, I get an 400 error from nginx saying this:

> 400 Bad Request
>
> The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

I am not entirely sure what to do, disabling the https with `ssl off;` has no effect. How can I actually disable HTTPS for domain1.org but not for domain2.com?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 running nginx 1.2.6.

Comment: What do you mean by "disable HTTPS for domain1.org"? What would it mean for HTTPS to be "disabled" for a host name? It's not clear what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Even with SNI you won't be able to *disable* SSL for a hostname on the same IP address.  Why do you consider a timeout or reset connection to be better than an SSL certificate error?  Why not just get an SSL certificate for that hostname too?

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to do what you want. You either:

1. Need to obtain a valid certificate for both domains and use the serverHost directives to redirect off SSL (to http://) if you truly don't want to run SSL on that domain.
2. Need to obtain a second IP address and run the domains on seperate IP addresses.
3. Leave SSL Enabled and serve an invalid certificate for domain1

**WHY:**

1. A client types https://domain1.com/ in a browser
2. The browser resolves this to a TCP connection to  on port 443
3. The magic of the internet routes this connection to your server and hopefully into your web server software
4. The client browser is standing at the front door waiting for the proper 'secret handshake' (SSL Cert.)
5. Your server tries the only handshake it knows (which is wrong)
6. The client's browser informs the client that "This guy at the door of domain1.com... He's not who he says he is. This is sketchy"
7. Today,  will click the variant of "Proceed Anyway" that their browser presents
8. IF you disable SSL on domain1.com, the user will be shown the other site (**quite confusing for the user**)
9. IF you leave SSL enabled on domain1.com, modern browsers and webservers will communicate and show the correct site. (**albeit, with a scary warning)**

---

If you intend to host domain1.org @ ip on port 80
and domain2.org at ip on port 443 (so that domain2 does not have HTTP access, it should 'work'). Remove the 443 listener for domain1. You will be prompted if any audacious users type https://domain1.org (and then shown domain2). That setup is essentially Port based virtual hosting.Instead of picking random ports you have picked the two defaults and given them to separate virtual hosts. Ultimately in this setup (WITH SSL laying around) the webserver doesn't really care what domain the browser is asking for in the Host header. The web server just cares about the ip:port combo in port based virtual hosts.

Comment: I have acquired a 2nd IP. Could you kindly show me how you would produce the configuration files to adapt the 2nd IP separately from the 1st IP. I am using `listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80` and listen `xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl` to try capture and redirect from `https://domain1.org` to `http://domain1.org` but I still get the HTTPS warning error, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

That's a quite common problem with http and https sites and not only a Nginx issue. You can have the same with Apache, IIS ... and whatever.

### How to solve this correctly

Acquire an additional IP address for your Web server and address domain2.org to the new IP (IP #2). Additionally take care that your Web server is listening only on port 80 via IP #1 and is listening on ports 80 and 443 via IP #2.

### Work-around if second IP not possible

If an additional IP address is not possible you can only implement a work-around. Activate SSL/TLS for domain1.org with the certificate of domain2.org and provide a redirect to http://domain1.org/ as you already did. Users will get SSL/TLS warnings anyway and most of them ignore these warnings. But so they get forwarded to the correct URL.

Example configuration for nginx:

```
ssl_certificate                 /etc/ssl/certs/domain2.org.pem;
ssl_certificate_key             /etc/ssl/private/domain2.org.key;
ssl_protocols                   SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;
ssl_ciphers                     AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH;
ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:10m;

# domain1.org
server {
    listen          80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     domain1.org;
    # your configuration part ...
}
server {
    listen          443 ssl spdy;
    listen          [::]:443 ssl spdy;
    server_name     domain1.org;
    return          301 http://domain1.org/;  # enforce correct protocol
}

# domain2.org
server {
    listen          80;
    listen          [::]:80;
    server_name     domain2.org;
    return          301 https://domain2.org/;  # enforce correct protocol
}
server {
    listen          443 default_server ssl spdy;
    listen          [::]:443 default_server ssl spdy;
    server_name     domain2.org;
    # your configuration part ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I have acquired a 2nd IP. Could you kindly show me how you would produce the configuration files to adapt the 2nd IP separately from the 1st IP. I am using `listen xx.xx.xx.xx:80;` and `listen xx.xx.xx.xx:443 ssl` to try capture and redirect from `https://domain1.org` to `http://domain1.org` but I still get the HTTPS warning error, unfortunately.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793827/multiple-ipsdomainsssl-certs-for-one-web-site

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understand what it is you are trying to do, it is impossible. SSL is either enabled on an IP address and port or it's not. What host name you use to reach that IP address has no effect on SSL itself except that some browsers send it during the negotiation process. But if you disabled SSL, there would be no negotiation, and then you wouldn't know what host they were trying to reach. So that can't work.